# Broadcast STL Map using MPI

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, stl, mpi

I have a variable looks like this

```
map< string, vector<double> > a_data;
```

long story short, a_data can be filled only by node 0. Hence, broadcasting it using MPI_Bcast() is necessary.

As we know that we can only use primitive data type. So, how should I do to broadcast STL datatype like map using MPI_Bcast()??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that you can do is to:

- first broadcast the number of keys to every process; So that every process knows the number of keys that will have to compute;
- broadcast an array that has coded the size of each of those keys;
- broadcast another array that has coded the size of each array of values;
- create a loop to iterate over the keys;
- broadcast first the key string (as an array of chars);
- broadcast next the values as an array of doubles.

So in pseudo-code would look like:

```
// number_of_keys <- get number of keys from a_data;
// MPI_Bcast() number_of_keys;
// int key_sizes[number_of_keys];
// int value_sizes[number_of_keys];
//
// if(node == 0){ // the root process 
//    for every key in a_data do
//        key_sizes[i] = the size of the key;
//        value_sizes[i] = size of the vector of values associated to key
// }
// 
//  MPI_Bcast() the array key_sizes
//  MPI_Bcast() the array value_sizes
// 
// for(int i = 0; i < number_of_keys; i++){
//     key <- get key in position 0 from a_data
//     values <- get the values associated with the key
//
//     MPI_Bcast() the key and use the size stored on key_sizes[i]
//     MPI_Bcast() the values and use the size stored on value_sizes[i]
//
//     // Non root processes
//     if(node != 0){ 
//       add key to the a_data of the process
//       add the values to the corresponded key
//     }
// }
```

You just need to adapt the code to C++ (which I am not an expert) so you might have to adapt a bit, but the big picture is there. After having the approach working you can optimized further by reducing the number of broadcast needed. That can be done by packing more information *per* broadcast. For instance, you can broadcast first the number of items, the sizes of the keys and values, and finally the keys and the values together. For the latter you would need to create your custom MPI Datatype similar to the example showcased [here](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/349/introduction-to-mpi/custom-types).

Comment: Or simply use `boost::mpi` and broadcast almost arbitrarily complex C++ types in a single line of code.

Comment: Boost is to C++ what LAPACK is to Fortran. The inclusion of MPI primitives in Boost is what prompted the removal of the C++ bindings from the standard.

Comment: Sadly, i don't wanna put such big libraries in my code. Moreover, my cluster only supports C++-03. So using Boost is not a choice.

Comment: There are boost versions from that far back. `boost::mpi` is from 2005